# Beautiful Soup - Export to Text File

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying beautiful soup, and I want to export it into a text file.

How to change the `result.txt` file name into the text from `soup.find(class_="entry-title").get_text()`?

Thanks in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.request

#getting the page.
url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.haripuisi.com/arsip/3163').read()
soup = bs(url, 'lxml')

#extracting the content.
print (soup.find(class_="entry-title").get_text())
print (soup.find(class_="entry-content").get_text())

#save into text file.
save_file = open(r'C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\tempting texting\result.txt', 'w')
save_file.write(soup.find(class_="entry-content").get_text())
save_file.close()
```

Comment: what problems are you facing with this solution ?

Comment: found the problem. must replace the " : " character in the title to another character, in order to save file.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename= soup.find(class_="entry-title").get_text()+".txt"
save_file = open(filename, 'w+')
save_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I use python2.7, so you need to change something bellow：

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib


url = urllib.urlopen('http://www.haripuisi.com/arsip/3163').read()
soup = bs(url, 'lxml')
print (soup.find(class_="entry-title").get_text())
print (soup.find(class_="entry-content").get_text())

file_name= soup.find(class_="entry-title").get_text() 

save_file = open("/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/%s.txt"%file_name, "w")
save_file.write(soup.find(class_="entry-content").get_text())
save_file.close()
```

I get the file:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: i've renamed the entry title into variable called "title" then change the code into this: open(r'C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\tempting texting\%s.txt' % title, 'w') tried this, didn't work. open(r'C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\tempting texting\{}.txt'.format(title), 'w') also tried this, didn't work. i'm using 3.6.1.